# ¿Cómo importar y exportar documentos PDFs en Python con nombres de variable?

Tags: python, pdf, git-merge, exportar, xdocument

Estoy leyendo un listado a partir de un excel, en el que en cada fila hace referencia a nombres de archivos.

Lo que necesito es leer de cada fila, los nombres que aparecen en las diferentes columnas. Todos esos nombres hacen referencia a diferentes PDF. Eso ya lo he conseguido, entonces saco, en un bucle, cada nombre y lo convierto en un vector, en el que cada casilla del vector es el nombre de un PDF.

Entonces necesito coger todos esos PDFs, y exportar un único PDF por cada vector.

El problema radica en que para importar un PDF, la única forma que conozco es llamando al documento por su nombre de la forma: "DocumentoX.pdf". ¿Cómo puedo importar un PDF con un nombre en función de las variables que voy sacando? Por ejemplo: insertar un PDF que se llame como la primera posición del primer vector.

Muchas gracias.

Adjunto el código que tengo hecho por ahora:

```
import xlrd
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger
import docx
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

archivo= 'prueba.xlsx'
documento = xlrd.open_workbook(archivo)
hoja1=documento.sheet_by_index(0)

fusionador = PdfFileMerger

n_filas = hoja1.nrows
n_columnas = hoja1.ncols
print ("numero de filas es: ", n_filas)
print ("numero de columnas es: ", n_columnas)


i=0 #Fila
j=1 #Columna



for i in range (n_filas):
    nombre_propietario = []
    vector_catastrales = []
    #print (hoja1.cell_value(i,0))
    for j in range (1, n_columnas):
        contenido_celda=hoja1.cell_value(i,j)
        if (contenido_celda != ''):
            vector_catastrales.append(contenido_celda)
    nombre_propietario.append (hoja1.cell_value(i,0))
    archivo_1 = 'separata.pdf'
    archivo_2 = 'nombre_propietario.pdf'
    print(archivo_2)
            
    print (hoja1.cell_value(i,0), vector_catastrales)
    fusionador.append(archivo_1, archivo_2, archivo_3)
```

Comment: En lo personal creo que el verdadero problema es que Python no tiene buenas librerías para liderar con archivos PDF. ¿Logras abrir al menos uno?

Comment: Buenos días. Logro abrir los archivos si escribo los nombres manualmente. El problema es cuando quiero "automatizar" los nombres, es decir, que el bucle me saque el nombre de los archivos, y que por ejemplo el "archivo_2" obtenga su nombre automáticamente del vector de "nombre_propietario". Gracias

Comment: ¿Logras meter los nombres de los archivos en una lista?

Comment: Así es. Tengo un bucle del que salen los vectores. Cada posición del vector es el nombre de un archivo a juntar. Entonces, lo que necesito saber, es como decirle al programa que busque en la carpeta los PDF que se llaman como cada casilla del vector y los junte. Necesito también que el nombre de salida sea automático.

Comment: Por cierto, la última línea de tu código es un error, ya que `append()` toma solo un valor a la vez. Debes añadir los archivos a la lista al interno del ciclo.

Comment: Tota la razón Ariel. Muchas gracias. Ya lo he solucionado en mi código :)

Comment: También puedes hacer `archivos=[archivo_1,archivo_2]` y luego con una segunda lista hacer `fusionador += archivos`. Pero el otro problema que veo es que `fusionador` no es una lista, en realidad es una función

Comment: Actualicé mi respuesta, ahora explica también como unir varios pdf y guardarlos en un nuevo archivo. (no lo he probado)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo necesitas un siclo `for`:

```
def lee(arhivo):
    "Abre archivo y devuelve su contenido"
    with open(archivo, 'r') as f:
        return f.read()

archivos=['archivo1.txt','archivo2.txt']
datos_de_archivos = [lee(a) for a in archivos]
```

Otra forma de hacer lo mismo, sin usar funciones ni list comprehension:

```
archivos=['archivo1.txt','archivo2.txt']
datos=[]

for a in archivos:
    with open(a, 'r') as f:
        datos.append(f.read())
```

Cómo aplicarlo a los pdf usando la librería PyPDF2:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader

archivos=['archivo1.pdf','archivo2.pdf']

# obtiene todas las paginas de los pdf
pdf = PdfFileMerger()    
for a in archivos:
    pdf.append(PdfFileReader(file(a, 'rb')))

# salva el documento
pdf.write("nuevo.pdf")
```

Comment: No se si esto resuelve mi duda. Olvidemos el programa. Imaginemos que tenemos un vector= [archivo1, archivo2, archivo3]. ¿Como podemos decirle al programa: une los tres archivos "archivo1.pdf", "archivo2.pdf", "archivo3.pdf", y exporta ese pdf nuevo con el nombre que sea "Archivo_restultante_i" (siendo esa i una variable que queremos que cambie)?

Comment: Debes leer cada archivo, colocando todo el contenido de los tres archivos en una misma variable (como se ve en mi respuesta) para luego poder guardar esos datos en un archivo nuevo que creas tu mismo (único paso que no hice). ¿Tu pregunta es sobre como crear un pdf o sobre como iterar en los nombres de variables para acceder a ellos?

Comment: Ariel, mil gracias por tus comentarios. He conseguido resolverlo. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entiendo, solamente quieres que tu archivo de salida pueda ir cambiando el nombre (supongo que para que no los sobreescriba), y por eso dices que podría ser con el nombre de la primera posición del vector.

Prueba con esto:

```
with open(archivo_1 , 'wb') as s:
    fusionador.write(s)
```

si no quieres que te sobreescriba el archivo_1 puedes añadirle por ejemplo un Nuevo_ delante:

```
with open('Nuevo_' + archivo_1 , 'wb') as s:
    fusionador.write(s)
```